# Создание базы данных интернет магазина

Tags: sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет лучше сделать "атрибуты" для товаров, например цвет, размер и т.д.
Я сделал так:

AttributeType

```
[id]
[Name]
```

AttributeValue

```
[Id]
[Value]
```

ProductAttribute

```
[Id]
[AttributeValueId]
[ProductId]
[IsInStock]
[AttributeTypeId]
```

У товара не обязательно должны быть какие-то атрибуты.
Отдельно сделал таблицы AttributeType и AttributeValue чтобы не надо было для каждого товара заново добавлять те же значения размеров/цветов и т.д.

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: на странице товара, при наличии цветов, нужно сделать кружочки с цветами(ну типо как на маркетплейсах бывает).
Но как мне понять, что это цвет?
Планируется, что будут "модераторы", которые могут на сайте менять, добавлять и атрибуты и товары.
Сравнивать Name у AttributeTypе со строкой "color" не лучший вариант, ибо неизвестно что туда введет модератор, вдруг опечатается или еще что-то.
Как можно это реализивать?

Comment: EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value)

Comment: *как мне понять, что это цвет?* А это атрибут сущности Атрибут. С чего ты решил, что набор атрибутов одноуровневый?

Comment: Не смешивайте в голове данные и представление... Данные из БД должны преобразовываться в предметную модель, т.е. в БД у Вас в качестве значения может находиться целочисленное значение, а в предметной области (классах) это будет перечислением (IN_STOCK, DELIVERED, NOT_IN_STOCK). Как визуально представлять те или иные свойства/атрибуты решает клиент (web - одно, консоль - другое). Для свойств у Вас должны быть определены типы и при необходимости их иерархия. Переопределение способов отображения является академическим примером полиморфизма.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Где-то должно быть зафиксировано значение AttributeTypeId, которое будет считаться главным, выводимым в кружочках.

Можно добавить его непосредственно в таблицу Product, и заполнять для каждого товара.

Когда проектировал совой абстрактный интернет-магазин, пришёл к мысли, что должен быть справочник категорий товаров (возможно иерархический), и справочник соответствий для каких категорий применимы какие атрибуты.

В таком случае можно закрепить главный (выводимый в кружочке) атрибут в таблице категорий.

Answer (score 0):

По своему опыту: я бы ещё посоветовал к каждому ID в таблицах дописать имя таблицы, чтоб потом не путаться в ID при сборе запросов или обращении к данным, к примеру, в таблице `AttributeType` не просто `id`, а `idAttributeType`. в таблице `ProductAttribute` - `idProductAttribute`